# Nexus Can't Download Remote Repo Index

Tags: maven, indexing, repository, nexus

I have Nexus 1.9.0.2 and my Update Indexes task is broken.  The logs show this error:

```
2013-09-17 08:47:50 WARN  [pool-1-thread-4] - o.s.n.i.DefaultInde~          - Cannot fetch remote index for repository opennms-repo
java.io.FileNotFoundException: nexus-maven-repository-index.71.gz (item not found)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager$2.retrieve(DefaultIndexerManager.java:1095)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.loadIndexDirectory(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.access$300(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater$LuceneIndexAdaptor.addIndexChunk(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:635)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:156)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.updateRemoteIndex(DefaultIndexerManager.java:1111)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.downloadRepositoryIndex(DefaultIndexerManager.java:1013)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.reindexRepository(DefaultIndexerManager.java:897)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.reindexAllRepositories(DefaultIndexerManager.java:810)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.tasks.ReindexTaskHandlerLegacy.reindexAllRepositories(ReindexTaskHandlerLegacy.java:47)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.tasks.AbstractIndexerTask.doRun(AbstractIndexerTask.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.scheduling.AbstractNexusTask.call(AbstractNexusTask.java:192)
    at org.sonatype.scheduling.DefaultScheduledTask.call(DefaultScheduledTask.java:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:207)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.ItemNotFoundException: The remoteURL we requested does not exists on remote server (remoteUrl="http://repo.opennms.org/content/repositories/opennms-repo/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.71.gz")
    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.storage.remote.commonshttpclient.CommonsHttpClientRemoteStorage.retrieveItem(CommonsHttpClientRemoteStorage.java:248)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager$2.retrieve(DefaultIndexerManager.java:1078)
    ... 20 more
```

and later this one:

```
2013-09-17 08:56:53 INFO  [pool-1-thread-4] - o.s.n.f.DefaultFeed~          - Updating all registered repositories index : Process started on Tue Sep 17 08:44:32 MDT 2013, finished on Tue Sep 17 08:56:53 MDT 2013 with error. Error message is: java.io.IOException, Error scanning context opennms-sonatype-ctx: java.lang.NullPointerException Strack trace: java.io.IOException: Error scanning context opennms-sonatype-ctx: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.index.DefaultNexusIndexer.scan(DefaultNexusIndexer.java:300)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.reindexRepository(DefaultIndexerManager.java:903)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.reindexAllRepositories(DefaultIndexerManager.java:810)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.tasks.ReindexTaskHandlerLegacy.reindexAllRepositories(ReindexTaskHandlerLegacy.java:47)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.tasks.AbstractIndexerTask.doRun(AbstractIndexerTask.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.scheduling.AbstractNexusTask.call(AbstractNexusTask.java:192)
    at org.sonatype.scheduling.DefaultScheduledTask.call(DefaultScheduledTask.java:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:207)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.IndexUtils.updateTimestamp(IndexUtils.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.updateTimestamp(DefaultIndexingContext.java:418)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.updateTimestamp(DefaultIndexingContext.java:408)
    at org.apache.maven.index.DefaultNexusIndexer.scan(DefaultNexusIndexer.java:293)
    ... 13 more

java.io.IOException: Error scanning context opennms-sonatype-ctx: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.index.DefaultNexusIndexer.scan(DefaultNexusIndexer.java:300)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.reindexRepository(DefaultIndexerManager.java:903)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager.reindexAllRepositories(DefaultIndexerManager.java:810)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.tasks.ReindexTaskHandlerLegacy.reindexAllRepositories(ReindexTaskHandlerLegacy.java:47)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.tasks.AbstractIndexerTask.doRun(AbstractIndexerTask.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.scheduling.AbstractNexusTask.call(AbstractNexusTask.java:192)
    at org.sonatype.scheduling.DefaultScheduledTask.call(DefaultScheduledTask.java:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:207)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.IndexUtils.updateTimestamp(IndexUtils.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.updateTimestamp(DefaultIndexingContext.java:418)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.updateTimestamp(DefaultIndexingContext.java:408)
    at org.apache.maven.index.DefaultNexusIndexer.scan(DefaultNexusIndexer.java:293)
    ... 13 more
```

I can hit the repo URL (http://repo.opennms.org/content/repositories/opennms-repo/) in a browser just fine.  However, the URL to the index (http://repo.opennms.org/content/repositories/opennms-repo/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.71.gz) is busted.

How does Nexus/Maven determine the URL to the index file?  Is this a Maven/Nexus issue or an issue with the repo?

Answer (score 0):

See at this url: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-4140 maybe there is a bug into the version you used.